# Did they have a de-Britification coach for Lord of the Rings?

Tags: dialogue, the-lord-of-the-rings, acting

I notice that the actors in the film series of Lord of the Rings are mostly British, Australian or New Zealanders, but they for the most part lack the British mannerisms, accent and modes of speech that those people usually exhibit. For example, I recently saw the film "Atomica" which features Dominic Monaghan in it and he has all the usual British behaviors and verbal tics in that film.

So, how did they keep these sorts of affectations out of the Lord of the Rings? Did they have a de-Britification coach or something?

Comment: I know it's tough to prove a negative, but what "mannerisms, accent and modes of speech" are missing, specifically? Sean Bean's Yorkshire accent,  Sir Ian's plum-in-mouth Shakespearian RP; Merry, or was it Pippin's Scots lilt… or is it that no-one, even once, says "Cor Blimey, Guv'nor" ?

Comment: As a Brit, I don't know what was missing from various actors performances that could be called "de-Britification" - they all talked like Brits I've met. In fact, non-British actors such as Viggo Mortenson, Liv Tyler and Sean Astin all put on decidedly British accents (to varying degrees of success).

Comment: This would make more sense if specific examples of affectation were given.

Comment: @Mike Pretty much any scene in Atomica in which Dominic Monaghan is talking.

Answer (score 4):

They had hired dialect coaches (Roisin Carty and Andrew Jack) to find real-world accents that would work well for the various peoples of Middle-Earth. Dialogues had to be assimilated such that characters who come from the same Middle-Earth region would also sound similar.

For example, the Hobbits need to sound similar, since they grew up together in The Shire, whereas their actors come from different regions of the world. Roisin Carty says that the Hobbits' accent is loosely based on a west country accent [(source)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8JB9SF7yfY). I've also watched a short interview where Andrew Jack talks about his work. He says: "For the Hobbits we particular chose Gloucestershire." [(source)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zk78CwEoVb0)

In consequence, some actors don't speak their usual dialects in Lord Of The Rings. Apparently back then, a few people even thought Elijah Wood was English due to his acquired accent. All in all, I don't think there is any form of systematic "de-Britification".

Answer (score -2):

I did some additional research and found out the answer. The LOTR series had not just one, but two "dialect coaches," Andrew Jack and Roisin Carty. It was their job to make sure all the actors had "natural" accents and verbal manners that would be consistent with the environment of Middle Earth.

Comment: "Middle Earth" was designed, constructed & written by a Brit. It's not too far from expectation that any dialect coach would be there to ensure the 'foreigners' got their Brit right, rather than the opposite - Sean Astin with his 'slightly West Country' etc. I'd be extremely surprised if Bean or McKellern needed that kind of coaching. Though all Hobbits came from Hobbiton, no 2 had the same accent;) LOTR is definitely not as accent/region oriented as Game of Thrones [for which some actors deserved a medal & others an early death]. There was a lot of leeway in how the actors could characterise.

Comment: @Tetsujin The question is not about the nature of the LOTR dialect. The question is whether the producers took active steps to to avoid verbal British affectations from occurring in the movie. Since Monaghan's everyday voice, as exhibited in "Atomica" has those affectations, but they are absent in LOTR, the question is a reasonable one. And, as it turns out there was exactly such voice coaching during filming, as I pointed out in my answer.

Comment: You have yet to describe, even vaguely, those "affectations". You're not going to hang this entirely on one actor's accent in two different movies. That's just an untenable claim.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't have to. That has nothing to do with the question. The question is whether the producers took active steps to manage the accents in LOTR and the answer is yes, they hired two voice coaches both of whom have given interviews about managing accents during filming. I feel like I am repeating myself.

Comment: No, really. Do movies have dialogue coaches? Yes. Does having a dialog coach on LOTR prove they were "removing Britishisms"? Not in the slightest.

Comment: Absolutely not. You are now becoming intentionally offensive & still with **no** explanation whatsoever of what you actually are asking in your question. My objection is that you lump us all in as the same, without explanation or apology. It's long been a joke in the UK that Americans can't tell the difference between Australian & British, yet the Brits can nail a British accent easily to within 50 miles. You are really going to have to fully define your question, without prejudice.